# Display mini Page Layout with Lightning view

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, mini-page-layout

I am trying to display popOver with lightning view without developing any code as we do in classic. Is this possible? Have anyone tried this?

Comment: Also trying to figure this out, without writing a completely custom popover. Any way to hijack the popover functionality used all throughout LEX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interestingly the popOver hover fields in lightning are derived from the first four fields on the compact layout .

[image]

[image]